# How can i make anchor link # when url visited directly it focus on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

For instance i have this

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#section2">Hello World</a>
```

and when i provided the url to another person such as for instance `example.com/test.html#section2`
and they visited it i want the browser to somewhat show or focus on
Hello World which is the a content what `a href` is linking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the "id" of the element you want to be in view when you visit that link:

```html
<a href="#section2">Go to Section 2</a>
<div>
  <h1 id="section2">Section 2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: that work i used `span` thanks                                                                                          `<span id="section2"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#section2">Hello World</a></span>`